# Create a New big Object Wizard: ASp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wizard

Here's my question:
I need to write a wizard, for customers to "create a new" very big objetc, with some other asociated with it: for example, Some images stored in another table (with relationships), some Lat's and Lang's for google earth, etc.
Each of them are stored in diferent tables in the Database, and that's why, i have to first insert to get the first object's Database generated ID to make the relationships with the another Objects. That's the reason I think puttin' Everything on just one View and hide selective DIVs with Jquery is not one of my option.
Session isn't an option because of the bigger object.
And because of the type of website, the wizard MUST be as follows:

1. Basic details of objetct 1
2. Images of object 1 (I will need here the ID of the first object)
3. Geolocations (with google maps, as before)
4. More details of object 1.
5. Preview
6. Publish

The point is, in step 4, user fill some fields that are required by the DB, and I cannot make them nullable as is it part of the customers reqs.

If somebody can a least give Ideas, will be nice...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that storing your object in Session is not desirable because of the size of the object.  An alternative is to serialize that object and store it in the database.  As the user progresses through the wizard, that object gets retrieved, updated and stored back in as a blob.  Once they publish it, you can insert the appropriate records and remove the serialized object from whatever table you're storing them in.